# Excel Stacked Area Chart Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to duplicate the results found in the following site:  http://peltiertech.com/?s=variable+column

The only difference is that I would like to use VBA code only to accomplish the end result.  I would like to avoid referencing any fields on a worksheet.  The end result creates columns with variable widths.  I have confirmed that the process described on the website works when using data on a worksheet.  I just can’t make the transition to getting the same result with only using code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub RangeTest()

Dim MyArray1(1 To 14) As Variant
Dim MyArray2(1 To 14) As Variant
Dim MyArray3(1 To 14) As Variant
Dim MyArray4(1 To 14) As Variant
Dim MyArray5(1 To 14) As Variant

    MyArray1(1) = 0
    MyArray1(2) = 0
    MyArray1(3) = 12.5
    MyArray1(4) = 25
    MyArray1(5) = 25
    MyArray1(6) = 50
    MyArray1(7) = 75
    MyArray1(8) = 75
    MyArray1(9) = 112.5
    MyArray1(10) = 150
    MyArray1(11) = 150
    MyArray1(12) = 200
    MyArray1(13) = 250
    MyArray1(14) = 250

    MyArray2(1) = 0
    MyArray2(2) = 100
    MyArray2(3) = 100
    MyArray2(4) = 100
    MyArray2(5) = 0
    MyArray2(6) = 0
    MyArray2(7) = 0
    MyArray2(8) = 0
    MyArray2(9) = 0
    MyArray2(10) = 0
    MyArray2(11) = 0
    MyArray2(12) = 0
    MyArray2(13) = 0
    MyArray2(14) = 0

    MyArray3(1) = 0
    MyArray3(2) = 0
    MyArray3(3) = 0
    MyArray3(4) = 0
    MyArray3(5) = 75
    MyArray3(6) = 75
    MyArray3(7) = 75
    MyArray3(8) = 0
    MyArray3(9) = 0
    MyArray3(10) = 0
    MyArray3(11) = 0
    MyArray3(12) = 0
    MyArray3(13) = 0
    MyArray3(14) = 0

    MyArray4(1) = 0
    MyArray4(2) = 0
    MyArray4(3) = 0
    MyArray4(4) = 0
    MyArray4(5) = 0
    MyArray4(6) = 0
    MyArray4(7) = 0
    MyArray4(8) = 50
    MyArray4(9) = 50
    MyArray4(10) = 50
    MyArray4(11) = 0
    MyArray4(12) = 0
    MyArray4(13) = 0
    MyArray4(14) = 0

    MyArray5(1) = 0
    MyArray5(2) = 0
    MyArray5(3) = 0
    MyArray5(4) = 0
    MyArray5(5) = 0
    MyArray5(6) = 0
    MyArray5(7) = 0
    MyArray5(8) = 0
    MyArray5(9) = 0
    MyArray5(10) = 0
    MyArray5(11) = 25
    MyArray5(12) = 25
    MyArray5(13) = 25
    MyArray5(14) = 0

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=900, Top:=265, Height:=245).Name = "Testing1"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Testing1").Chart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Testing1").Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlTimeScale

        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Testing1").Chart
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = MyArray1
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = MyArray2
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Alpha"
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = MyArray1
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = MyArray3
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Beta"
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = MyArray1
            .SeriesCollection(3).Values = MyArray4
            .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Gamma"
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(4).XValues = MyArray1
            .SeriesCollection(4).Values = MyArray5
            .SeriesCollection(4).Name = "Delta"
        End With

End Sub
```

This creates the chart but does not make the conversion to variable column width.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what went wrong.

I didn't change much of your code, just rearranged it to make it more readable and maybe more efficient.

```
Sub RangeTest()
  Dim MyChart As ChartObject

  Dim MyArray1(1 To 14) As Variant
  Dim MyArray2(1 To 14) As Variant
  Dim MyArray3(1 To 14) As Variant
  Dim MyArray4(1 To 14) As Variant
  Dim MyArray5(1 To 14) As Variant

  MyArray1(1) = 0
  MyArray1(2) = 0
  MyArray1(3) = 12.5
  MyArray1(4) = 25
  MyArray1(5) = 25
  MyArray1(6) = 50
  MyArray1(7) = 75
  MyArray1(8) = 75
  MyArray1(9) = 112.5
  MyArray1(10) = 150
  MyArray1(11) = 150
  MyArray1(12) = 200
  MyArray1(13) = 250
  MyArray1(14) = 250

  MyArray2(1) = 0
  MyArray2(2) = 100
  MyArray2(3) = 100
  MyArray2(4) = 100
  MyArray2(5) = 0
  MyArray2(6) = 0
  MyArray2(7) = 0
  MyArray2(8) = 0
  MyArray2(9) = 0
  MyArray2(10) = 0
  MyArray2(11) = 0
  MyArray2(12) = 0
  MyArray2(13) = 0
  MyArray2(14) = 0

  MyArray3(1) = 0
  MyArray3(2) = 0
  MyArray3(3) = 0
  MyArray3(4) = 0
  MyArray3(5) = 75
  MyArray3(6) = 75
  MyArray3(7) = 75
  MyArray3(8) = 0
  MyArray3(9) = 0
  MyArray3(10) = 0
  MyArray3(11) = 0
  MyArray3(12) = 0
  MyArray3(13) = 0
  MyArray3(14) = 0

  MyArray4(1) = 0
  MyArray4(2) = 0
  MyArray4(3) = 0
  MyArray4(4) = 0
  MyArray4(5) = 0
  MyArray4(6) = 0
  MyArray4(7) = 0
  MyArray4(8) = 50
  MyArray4(9) = 50
  MyArray4(10) = 50
  MyArray4(11) = 0
  MyArray4(12) = 0
  MyArray4(13) = 0
  MyArray4(14) = 0

  MyArray5(1) = 0
  MyArray5(2) = 0
  MyArray5(3) = 0
  MyArray5(4) = 0
  MyArray5(5) = 0
  MyArray5(6) = 0
  MyArray5(7) = 0
  MyArray5(8) = 0
  MyArray5(9) = 0
  MyArray5(10) = 0
  MyArray5(11) = 25
  MyArray5(12) = 25
  MyArray5(13) = 25
  MyArray5(14) = 0

  Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=900, Top:=265, Height:=245)
  With MyChart
    .Name = "Testing1"

    With .Chart
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = MyArray1
        .Values = MyArray2
        .Name = "Alpha"
      End With
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = MyArray1
        .Values = MyArray3
        .Name = "Beta"
      End With
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = MyArray1
        .Values = MyArray4
        .Name = "Gamma"
      End With
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = MyArray1
        .Values = MyArray5
        .Name = "Delta"
      End With

      .ChartType = xlAreaStacked
      With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        .MajorUnitScale = xlDays
        .MajorUnit = 50
      End With
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Jon,  Thanks for the attempt.  Sorry if my explanation was not clear.  when you go to the site you will see that the intent of the explanation on the site is to change an area chart into a variable width chart.  Excel currently does not support making the width of a bar chart different sizes.  This site shows a work around how you can use an area chart to accomplish the same outcome.  This is what I was trying to do.  There is only so much I can type here and don't have the ability to attach pictures.  The site mentioned in the original write up explains everything.

Comment: Yeah, it's my site.... There is no such thing in Excel as a variable width column chart, just the nifty way to fake it that I describe in that tutorial. You couldn't get the code to make a similar example using arrays, and that was the question I answered above.

Comment: Nice to meet the man behind the legend.  LOVE your site!!!  Lots of helpful stuff there.  If I figure something out I will let you know.  Thanks again for the follow up.